# Create a Canva tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [a several questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22canva%22) about using [Canva](https://www.canva.com/). But it won't let me create a tag because it's too close to [canvas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canvas). Please create a tag for it so I can hide questions about it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I learnt of a new moderator super power today: Bypassing the tag similarity check.

Anyway, here you go: [canva](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canva). I’ll leave the rest to you.